# Clone angular binded div without bindings

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to make a clone of div without saving binding (want to make disappear animation).

```
<div ng-bind="current.content"></div>
```

The idea is to make absolute positioned copy of div and animate it's leaving. 
But when I'm using `.clone()` it's clonning without saving content.
Any ideas?

Comment: please explain more..

Comment: i have div which changes binding when pressing "previous" and "next" buttons and want to animate content leaving.